# Creating an image view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've looked at loads of solutions to this answer but can't find one that works or explains why it's happening. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView : UIScrollView!
var imageView : UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    if let image = UIImage(named: "Instructions") {
        imageView.image = image
    }
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
}
```

And here is the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: You're not initialising imageView anywhere, so it's nil.

Comment: How do I initialise it in Swift? I thought passing it an image should automatically initialise it.

Comment: No. It doesn't exist, so you can't pass it an image. It's nil until you explicitly create it, just like it would be in Objective C. Is there a reason you're using an implicitly-unwrapped optional for it? Will you ever *need* it to be nil? (If not, just try `var imageView = UIImageView()`.)

Comment: I guess I was thinking of the initWithImage call in objective-c. I never need it to be nil, no.

Comment: This should solve the issue: `var imageView : UIImageView = UIImageView()`

Comment: @68cherries You don't need to specify the type if you use the constructor. That implies the type, so you can just have it like I put in my comment.

Comment: Thanks, yes the following worked: ```imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Instructions"))```. If you want to put it as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
var imageView = UIImageView()
```

...to declare and instantiate your UIImageView property.

As your code stands, you're declaring imageView as an implicitly-unwrapped optional value, and never actually initialising it, so it's nil. Instead, as you'd never want your property to be nil anyway, you should use a non-optional variable (`UIImageView` as opposed to `UIImageView!`) and construct it when you declare it.

I'm guessing you may have been tempted to use the optional type because of the existing UIScrollview declaration:

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView : UIScrollView!
```

The reason *that* one is an implicitly-unwrapped optional is because it's an IBOutlet, so when your view controller is constructed it will be nil, but it will be initialised by the framework "rehydrating" code that warms objects up from your nib (Storyboard) file. So it has to be optional, as it's (briefly) nil after init has run, but it'll be set up by the framework before any of your code gets to it, so making it implicitly unwrapped means less typing to access something you can trust to be non-nil.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've come across this error a few times today so it's nice to be able understand WHY it's happening/what I'm doing wrong.